# C# What's the difference between Action and event Action

Tags: c#

Reading some code I noticed that a few classes have Actions, but only some of them were also events:

```
public Action OnAction1;
```

```
public event Action OnAction2;
```

What is the difference?

Comment: You are asking the difference between a field and an event

Comment: Please explain, is an event not a field?

Comment: You'll want to start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/

Comment: @Moffen: Very roughly speaking Events work like Properties, whose type must be a delegate, and wich only have public add/remove accessors. And each of those things makes it distinct from run of the mill Fields. There is not quite a thing that is "opposite" to a field, but Events are pretty far away from it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's effectively the same as the difference between fields and properties, it adds a level of indirection to allow you to add or remove subscribers safely without exposing the underlying field much in the same way a property protects access to the field value.

```
public Action OnAction1; // field
public Action OnAction2 { get; set; } // property
public event Action OnAction3; // event
```

As with properties, events can be "auto-implemented" meaning that there's an underlying backing field generated for you.

Just like properties can have explicit getters and setters:

```
private Action onAction2;
public Action OnAction2
{
    get
    {
        return onAction2;
    }
    set
    {
        onAction2 = value;
    }
}
```

Events can have explicit add and remove handlers:

```
private Action onAction3;
public event Action OnAction3
{
    add
    {
        onAction3 += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        onAction3 -= value;
    }
}
```

There's no way an outside class can directly access the underlying `onAction3` field through the `OnAction3` event just as you cannot directly access the `onAction2` field through the `OnAction2` property.

And of course, by explicitly implementing these accessors, you can perform other actions as well such as value validation or transformation.